# Filling up object in Angular JS for Insert

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to prepare a JSON object in my controller. So that I can send that object to my REST service to insert. The thing is my JSON object is kind of tricky and has different levels.

```
    {
           "ilstbusError": [],
               "icdoQuestion": {
                   "idoQuestion": {
                         "questionId": 1,
                         "createdBy": 1,
                         "createdDate": "2015-03-21",
                         "isValid": 0,
                         "modifiedBy": 1,
                         "modifiedDate": "2015-03-21",
                         "questionHtml": "Is there good explanation of what dark matter could be in space?",
                         "questionTitle": "What is dark matter?",
                         "threadId": 1,
                         "updateSeq": 0
                         }
                     }
    }
```

It looks like above. So to fill this object i am trying to write below code.

```
 $scope.ibusQuestion.icdoQuestion.iQuestion.questionTitle = "questionTitle";
 $scope.ibusQuestion.icdoQuestion.iQuestion.questionHtml  = "questionHtml";
 $scope.ibusQuestion.icdoQuestion.iQuestion.threadId = 1;
 $scope.ibusQuestion.icdoQuestion.iQuestion.isValid = 0;
```

But it is giving me below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'icdoQuestion' of undefined
```

Anybody how can I achieve this?

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `icdoQuestion` base object first before assigning its properties:

```
$scope.ibusQuestion = {icdoQuestion: {iQuestion: {}}};

$scope.ibusQuestion.icdoQuestion.iQuestion.questionTitle = "questionTitle";
// ...
```

Or if you want to make it more fancy and not worry about defining entire nested object structure in advance, you can make use of Angular `$parse` service:

```
$parse('ibusQuestion.icdoQuestion.iQuestion.questionTitle').assign($scope, "questionTitle");
```

In this case you don't even need to define `$scope.ibusQuestion` at all, as Angular will create it for you if it can't find it on `$scope`.